# Windows XP SP3 unable to browser https website

Tags: windows-xp, https

I have this new installation of Windows XP SP3 which is able to browse http websites but not https.

What i suspect is that it's missing or the root certificates that come with it are already expired

I am not able to even run windows update because that's also https

I tried installing root certs from https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots but it didn't help

Following are list of certs i installed and the issue i am facing

[image: certs installed and issue]

Comment: If you use Firefox does this behavior exhbit itself?

Comment: Try to reset IE : Tools tab > Internet Options > restore Adanced Settings and Reset

Comment: I suspect you mistakenly have a MitM proxy configured.  If you do have a root certificate authority problem, the Symantec certificates, will do nothing to fix Windows Update. The only benign reason for this problem would be your system time isn't correct.

Comment: @Ramhound Firefox works fine only IE having issue and it's stupid IE 6. Also there is no proxy

Comment: @GAD3R already tried reset didn't help

Comment: Did Windows Update ever work on this machine?  The fact Firefox works means you do indeed have a certifcate problem.  The fastest way to solve that problem, is export the certficiates from a working Windows XP machine, and import them to the machine that isn't working.

Comment: @Ramhound this is a new installation of XP SP3, This is an old machine and the only one i have with a serial port so need to install an OS on it to connect to my sparc machine which doesn't have a Video port but only serial output

Comment: @Ramhound you are on roll with great ideas, i am going to power on my XP VM and export and import certs to this Physical Windows XP Machine

Comment: I have no idea what your trying to say.  Please clarify your statement.  You need to also verify you have the required [trusted root certificates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/293781) installed.  Please carefully submit responses.  You should update your question and mention the fact your running Windows XP within a virtual machine.

Comment: The core issue is IE not able to browse https sites

Comment: @Ramhound no this is a physical box, i was simply saying that i am going to export certs from a functional VM and then import to this physical XP

Comment: Importing certs from VM to this machine didn't help. maybe the issue is it's IE 6 and i am not sure how to upgrade to newer one without being able to use windows update

Comment: Okay it's fixed, i had to import all certs + WindowsXP-KB960714-x86-ENU. but it would help to have somebody else confirm this in future if this can be fixed by just installing WindowsXP-KB960714-x86-ENU

Comment: Did you install Windows Explorer 8?

Comment: After following these steps my windows update started working and then it auto upgraded to IE 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Imported Certs from a Windows XP VM to this Physical Machine
2. Install WindowsXP-KB960714-x86-ENU https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24775

It would help to have somebody else confirm it if just installing just KB960714 will fix the issue

Comment: When trying to install KB960714 i got the error saying "the version of windows you have installed does not match the update you are trying to install"